# Openpyxl Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

При парсинге я получаю описание товара. Когда я его записываю в Excel исчезают около половины текста причем не всегда
Вот пример того как производится запись:

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
wb.create_sheet(title='Первый лист', index=0)
sheet = wb['Первый лист']
sheet[f'A{x}'] = articul.strip()
sheet[f'B{x}'] = name.strip()
sheet[f'C{x}'] = good_options.strip()
sheet[f'D{x}'] = color.strip()
sheet[f'E{x}'] = size.strip()
sheet[f'F{x}'] = brend.strip()
sheet[f'G{x}'] = aviability.strip()
sheet[f'H{x}'] = your_price
sheet[f'I{x}'] = base_price
sheet[f'J{x}'] = comand_price
sheet[f'K{x}'] = roznichnaja_price
sheet[f'L{x}'] = str(description)
sheet[f'M{x}'] = write_url
wb.save(f'{file_name}.xlsx')`
```

Или же:

```
result.append(articul.strip())
result.append(name.strip())
result.append(good_options.strip())
result.append(color.strip())
result.append(size.strip())
result.append(brend.strip())
result.append(aviability.strip())
result.append(your_price)
result.append(base_price)
result.append(comand_price)
result.append(roznichnaja_price)
result.append(str(description))
result.append(write_url)
sheet.append(result)
```

Что я могу сделать чтобы не терять часть описания?

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете просто записать данные в лист. Вам нужно обратится к ячейке в данном листе
Например:

```
sheet['name'].cell(row_number, column_nember).value = your_string
```